# Mr.Holmes won't work on windows with exit error cote "Display/Display.txt has not been found"

Tags: python

Hey i've been trying to use the tool on windows ( windows 10 ) i followed the exact installation steps and everything went alright, but when i started the Mr.Holmes.py or used the .exe launcher i'd get an error "FILE Display/Display.txt HAS NOT BEEN FOUND EXIT..." followed by a python error here is the full error

```
←[31m[!]←[97mFILE Display/Display.txt HAS NOT BEEN FOUND EXIT...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PC\Desktop\OSINT\Mr.Holmes-master\Mr.Holmes-master\MrHolmes.py", line 39, in <module>
    Mode = Main.Controll_Display()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PC\Desktop\OSINT\Mr.Holmes-master\Mr.Holmes-master\MrHolmes.py", line 33, in Controll_Display
    return conf
           ^^^^
```

does anyone know why i get this and how to fix it ?

I was expecting it to just start like its shown on the github or setup video's,i desperately tried to create the txt file but it would pop with another error

```
←[31m[!]←[97mLOOKS LIKE THERE IS AN INVALID OPTION ACCEPTED ONLY 'Desktop' OR 'Mobile'

EXIT...
```

just to clarify, its not for malicious usage im just trying to get the software for a "class project" and i want to use it for a demonstration on my self.

Comment: looks like it gets created here https://github.com/Lucksi/Mr.Holmes/blob/master/install_Termux.sh#L264  (or here https://github.com/Lucksi/Mr.Holmes/blob/master/install.sh#L458)

Comment: i'll check that and see what i can do thanks